# Cannot Implement View.onClickListener in Adapter class

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

**ERROR:Class 'PersonViewHolder' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'**

While running in emulator, The toast message is displayed but listener block seems to be not working. I already gone through numerous threads in stack overflow but couldn't find a solution

Adapter Class

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    private String pName;
    private String pAge;
    private Context context;
    private List<Person> persons;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    TextView personRegno;
    TextView personOPno;
    TextView personDocName;
    TextView personGender;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    PersonViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personRegno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_Reg_no);
        personOPno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_op_no);
        personDocName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_doctor_name);
        personPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        personGender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_gender);
        final Context context = itemView.getContext();

        cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ithu thaan mudiyum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onItemClick(personName.getText().toString(),personAge.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }
}

    public RVAdapter(Context context, List<Person> persons, String pName, String pAge) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pAge = pAge;
        this.persons = persons; 
    }


    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, null);
        return new PersonViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        // Person persons = Person.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        holder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).getName());
        holder.personAge.setText(persons.get(position).getAge());
        holder.personRegno.setText(persons.get(position).getRegno());
        holder.personOPno.setText(persons.get(position).getopno());
        holder.personDocName.setText(persons.get(position).getDoctorname());
        holder.personGender.setText(persons.get(position).getGender());
        holder.personPhoto.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(persons.get(position).getImage()));
        holder.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(String personName, String personAge);
}
}
```

Recycler.java

```
public class Recycler extends Fragment {

public Recycler() {

}


List<Person> persons;
private String pName;
private String pAge;

RecyclerView rv;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    rv = (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    persons = new ArrayList<>();

    persons.add(
            new Person("Vijay", "22", "Male", "RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:64446", R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Vishnu", "23","Male", "RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666", R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Vaishnavi sulochana", "24","Female", "RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666", R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Ram", "25","Male", "RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666",R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Raja", "21","Male","RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666", R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Hari", "23", "Male","RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666",R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    persons.add(
            new Person("Hari", "23", "Male","RegNo:666", "Doctor:vishnu", "Opno:6666",R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp));

    //creating recyclerview adapter
    //RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(getContext(), persons);
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(getContext(),persons,pName,pAge);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(String textName, String textViewBrief){
            ServiceTable eventFragment = new ServiceTable();
            //replace content frame with your own view.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    ft.replace(R.id.main_container, eventFragment).commit();
        }
    });

    //RVAdapter myAdapter = new RVAdapter(persons, this);

    //setting adapter to recyclerview
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootview;
}

}
```

This is my first time posting a question. so please ignore formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `onClick` method if you implement `View.OnClickListener` but in your case you set listener like below

```
cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ithu thaan mudiyum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(listener!=null)
                listener.onItemClick(personName.getText().toString(),personAge.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

therefore you need to either delete `implements View.OnClickListener`or override its `onClick()` method like below in your view holder class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer!!. Deleting the implements View.OnClickListener does resolves the error but at run time it doesn't move to the next fragment. It just gives the toast message.

Comment: Problem fixed, I just copied setOnItemClickListener method accessed by onBindViewHolder inside the Viewholder class of RVAdapter and outside defined another setOnitemClickListener method with same body that is accessed in Recycler. This worked!!!!

Comment: i am glad if it helped you to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I certainly got the correct angle to view the problem from your answer. It actually helped me in some way.